# Questions on Office Js Capabilities

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have need to migratin the office addin built in VB to web.
i have worked with office js a bit but has few questions on what can and cannot be done with officejs

1. Can we develop form like vb forms, i have gone though dialog api which loads the external html file but not a internal form. Only way to is to use content pane ?
   2.How to add nested menu list in the ribbon
2. The addin built in office js works for office 365, offfice online as well
3. How to package the addin for Excel online  and office 365 ?

Highly appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put any HTML you want in the task pane, so you can basically make your own form (if I'm understanding the question correctly).
2. Add-ins are intended to be cross-platform. If you make an Excel add-in, you are able to have it run on Excel for Desktop, Excel for Mac, Excel for the web, and Excel for iOS. Some specific APIs only work on certain platforms or have limitations, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview).
3. You don't have to package your add-in differently for different platforms. All the client needs is the manifest file, which points to your webservice. You can read more about distribution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish?view=excel-js-preview).